# Building Tensorflow lite micro with C code

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, gnu-make

I want to use some C code in my tensorflow lite project, but all the example projects provided in the tensorflow lite repository are C++ examples.

In particular, I am using the AmbiqSDK repository, which provides examples for the apollo3 platform, and all the examples are in C, which I want to merge now with one of the tensorflow lite examples.

The relevant makefile parts are here:

```
MICRO_SPEECH_SRCS := \
tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/micro_speech/main.cc \
...
tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/micro_speech/command_responder.cc \
new_c_file_here.c \ ---->> HERE I LINK MY ADDITIONAL C CODE
$(MICRO_FEATURES_GENERATOR_SRCS)
...
# Builds a standalone speech command recognizer binary.
$(eval $(call microlite_test,micro_speech,\
$(MICRO_SPEECH_SRCS),$(MICRO_SPEECH_HDRS)))
...
# For normal manually-created TensorFlow C++ source files.
$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cc third_party_downloads
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
...
# For normal manually-created TensorFlow C source files.
$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c third_party_downloads
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

and in my new_c_file_here.c file, I've wrapped everything in extern "C"{}.

But I am still getting linker errors that I don't get when compiling the C++ tensorflow lite example project or the C apollo3 example project with their respective compiler:

> ....
>
> tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/gen/sparkfun_edge_cortex-m4/obj//Users/macuser/Desktop/tf115/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/downloads/AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/third_party/exactle/sw/hci/ambiq/apollo3/hci_drv_apollo3.o:
>   In function `HciDrvHandler':
>   /Users/macuser/Desktop/tf115/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/downloads/AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/third_party/exactle/sw/hci/ambiq/apollo3/hci_drv_apollo3.c:1099: undefined reference to`DmDevReset'
>   tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/gen/sparkfun_edge_cortex-m4/obj//Users/macuser/Desktop/tf115/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/downloads/AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/third_party/exactle/sw/profiles/hrps/hrps_main.o:
>   In function `hrpsFindNextToSend':
>   /Users/macuser/Desktop/tf115/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/downloads/AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/third_party/exactle/sw/profiles/hrps/hrps_main.c:125:
>   undefined reference to`AttsCccEnabled'
>   tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/gen/sparkfun_edge_cortex-m4/obj//Users/macuser/Desktop/tf115/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/downloads/AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/third_party/exactle/sw/profiles/hrps/hrps_main.o:
>   In function `hrpsSendHrmNtf':
>   /Users/macuser/Desktop/tf115/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/downloads/AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/third_party/exactle/sw/profiles/hrps/hrps_main.c:204:
>   undefined reference to`AttsHandleValueNtf'
>
> ....

How can I compile the C code in my tensorflow lite C++ project correctly?

I am using Tensorflow 1.15.0.

Comment: Are you able to find in which files are `AttsCccEnabled` and `AttsHandleValueNtf` defined?

Answer (score 0):

i am using TFlite to make a project using AmbiqSDK too ,i will explain to you how i made the interface :
but first you have to know that TF is written in C++ , it is better to compile it so .

for example in PDM .h/.c

```
PDM_mein.c -> write your code exactly in C

        void pdm_data_get(void)
{
    am_hal_pdm_transfer_t sTransfer;
    sTransfer.ui32TargetAddr = (uint32_t )  g_ui32PDMDataBuffer;
    
    sTransfer.ui32TotalCount = PDM_FFT_BYTES;
    am_hal_pdm_enable(PDMHandle);
    am_hal_sysctrl_sleep(AM_HAL_SYSCTRL_SLEEP_DEEP);
    am_hal_pdm_fifo_flush(PDMHandle);
    am_hal_pdm_dma_start(PDMHandle, &sTransfer);
}
////////////////////////////////////
PDM_mein.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void pdm_data_get(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

when you write like this , you can use C function in C++ program
and dont forget to add .c and .h files in Makefile.inc